# SQL Code not executing properly

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, cursor

So I have this piece of code:

```
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM CustomerTable WHERE " + variable.get() + " = " + Queryby.get()
print(sql1)
```

and when I run this code, the `print` outputs this:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerTable WHERE Title = Mr
```

which suggests that the code should work when it is executed. However, when I change the `print(sql1)` to `cursor.execute(sql1)`, it outputs the following error message:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Mr
```

This is really confusing for me because of where the `Mr` is would suggest it is what is being searched for, not what the column is called. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `Mr` with a single apostrophe like so `'Mr'`. That way, SQL recognizes it as a string and not a column.

Basically, your line should be this:

```
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM CustomerTable WHERE " + variable.get() + " = '" + Queryby.get() + "'"
```

You may also format it differently if you wish to avoid all the plus signs like so:

```
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM CustomerTable WHERE {} = '{}'".format(variable.get(), Queryby.get())
```

Keep in mind formatting the string yourself might result in SQL injection attacks if the input is given from the outside. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) regarding formatting with `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing your query dynamically like this opens you to injection attacks when finally executed. Instead, use a parameterized query:

```
# This is a little extreme...
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM CustomerTable WHERE ? = ?"
cursor.execute(sql1, (variable.get(), Queryby.get()))
```

This relieves you of the job of making sure the dynamic elements are properly quoted.

Answer (score -1):

Add quotes around "Mr". Like:

```
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM CustomerTable WHERE " + variable.get() + " = '" + Queryby.get() + "'"
```

Comment: Probably because you are advocating code that is open to an SQL injection attack.

Comment: I made the smallest possible change to the original code to make it work. I wouldn't really call that "advocating"... Plus if the down voter was so concerned about me advocating insecure coding practices then he/she could have bothered to remark on that for others to know (and possibly for me to amend or even delete my answer)...